# Strange behaviour with arithmetic operations

Tags: php

I have following code for example:

```
<?php

print 1 - 0.8 - 0.2 . PHP_EOL;

print 1 - 0.2 - 0.8 . PHP_EOL;

print 1 - 0.2 . PHP_EOL; 

print 1 - 0.8 . PHP_EOL;

print 0.2 - 0.2 . PHP_EOL;
```

And after execution it has output:

```
-5.5511151231258E-17
0
0.8
0.2
0
```

How did **-5.5511151231258E-17** ? Why? I am confused...

Example link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc4c31db76fa9746d76e8ac7ac4042777e095b81

Comment: You do understand that `-5.5511151231258E-17` stands for `-0.000000000000000055511151231258`?

Comment: @deceze Yes, but i want to understand why) Thx for link to duplicate!